# Delphi remove tab space inside the source code

Tags: delphi

is there a shortcut do delete the tab space inside the source code

eg

```
procedure TForm1.Create(Sender: TObject);
begin
    showmessage('Test1');
    showmessage('Test2');
    showmessage('Test3');
end;
```

how I can make it like the below code

```
procedure TForm1.Create(Sender: TObject);
begin
  showmessage('Test1');
  showmessage('Test2');
  showmessage('Test3');
end;
```

is there i shortcut by select the text and press some keys to delete the tap space.

Thanks

Comment: `Shift + TAB` or e.g. `Ctrl + K & U`

Comment: @TLama: but only if you select the lines you want to change first.

Comment: CTRL+D would do it too......

Comment: Thank's David! CTRL + D was new to me. Now I can produce bonafide syntax :-)

Answer (score 3):

Select some text and use e.g. one of the following keyboard shortcuts:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> → <kbd>U</kbd>
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>